# Get confused about the implementation of Amplitude Amplifier

Tags: grovers-algorithm, amplitude-amplification

I have a circuit $A$, which produces
$$A|0^n\rangle _a |00\rangle _b = \phi_0 |00\rangle _b + \phi_1 |01\rangle _b+ \phi_2 |10\rangle _b + \phi_3 |11\rangle _b$$
And only $\phi_0 |00\rangle _b$ is what I want.

I think I can use amplitude amplifier to increase the probability to measure $00$ on register 'b' without messing up with $\phi _0$, where by quant-ph/0005055, I need an $S_0$ operator changes the sign of the coefficients of 'b' whenever 'b' is $|00\rangle _b$,

So I did this:
I append a qubit $|0\rangle _c - |1\rangle _c$, and implement the Q operator as
$Q=AS_0A^{\dagger}S_0$

where,
$$S_0=X(b_0)X(b_1) CCNOT(b_0,b_1,c) X(b_0)X(b_1)$$

That is, I implement this circuit: $QA|0^n\rangle_a|00\rangle_b\left(|0\rangle _c-|1\rangle _c\right)$

However, after only one iteration, the state at $|00\rangle _b$ changes.

I feel confused about the result, and don't know whether it was the misunderstanding about the amplitude amplifier algorithm. I have following questions:

1. In my case that I want to get $\phi _0$ with higher probability, is amplitude amplifier appropriate for my problem?
2. If amplitude amplifier should work in my case, should I implement $S_0$ as an operator just flip the sign of $|00\rangle _b$?
3. If my understanding was correct that $S_0$ is an operator just flip the sign of $|00\rangle _b$, should I implement $S_0$ as a toffoli gate taking 'b' as controller on an ancilla 'c' which is initialized as $|0\rangle -|1\rangle$?

I need your help!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that, the $S_0$ are not the same.

The first $S_0$ is acting on both $a$ and $b$ qubits, such that

$$AS_0A^{\dagger}=AA^{\dagger}-2A|0\rangle \langle 0 |A^{\dagger}=1-2|\psi\rangle \langle \psi |$$.

The second $S_0$ act on only $b$ qubits, in this case it is,

$$S_0^b=1_a\otimes \left(1-2|00\rangle _b \langle 00 |_b\right)$$,

which is $1-2P$, where $P$ is the projection onto the correct state.

Then, everything works.

Comment: Your second $S_0$ is actually $S_{\chi}$ from the referenced paper $-$ it flips the sign of your desired component and ignores the others. It can act only on $b$ qubits in your case, but generally acts on $a$ and $b$. 
The first $S_0$ must act on both $a$ and $b$, that's correct.